# Python: How to decrypt a token

Tags: python, cryptography, aes

The following script should decrypt the token "djEwe5t74Rc5Ded4Ozm++rCKmYTCd7wxI1X6L1GywnslmeUs4240q72bcuotAMSp2p3S2ovrqQoFLRNJ9GzelmF+beLrVJfPnT7cdg+7e+ZRYBfn9uiTL/4VkL8Sp24TTgoVrDA+gg==" with the encryption key

```
{"os_crypt":{"encrypted_key":"RFBBUEkBAAAA0Iyd3wEV0RGMegDAT8KX6wEAAACwiiOT7hVKSpqHHKmfelp6AAAAAAIAAAAAABBmAAAAAQAAIAAAAEr1FtZCawv6cT1z5zzXxZ30h4O7Ity3EBLfTdtM0oO6AAAAAA6AAAAAAgAAIAAAACpGZwsT0RKSCl/ukX6ZxNytKpAbHgRmqLqpRW++TcxEMAAAAC8HEpNDthKadJlMBCAvonE1QXVGTjE4Hh0TJv75iz48R2eb93lG9zxpr8xhh1C7e0AAAAAWODcIFOqibQmHRL/fnDgtFy7JdNC7NynDGMtcucS4R5yD92+2UFPFquqfEbpu/gIW5eMv3LQIQDJlR5I53KRs"}}
```

The script is as follows

```py
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData

# Función decrypt_val
def decrypt_val(buff: bytes, master_key: bytes) -> str:
    iv = buff[3:15]
    payload = buff[15:]

    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(master_key), modes.GCM(iv), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    decrypted_pass = decryptor.update(payload) + decryptor.finalize()[:-16]
    decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
    return decrypted_pass

# Función get_master_key
def get_master_key() -> bytes:
    # Esta es la master_key proporcionada
    master_key = "RFBBUEkBAAAA0Iyd3wEV0RGMegDAT8KX6wEAAACwiiOT7hVKSpqHHKmfelp6AAAAAAIAAAAAABBmAAAAAQAAIAAAAEr1FtZCawv6cT1z5zzXxZ30h4O7Ity3EBLfTdtM0oO6AAAAAA6AAAAAAgAAIAAAACpGZwsT0RKSCl/ukX6ZxNytKpAbHgRmqLqpRW++TcxEMAAAAC8HEpNDthKadJlMBCAvonE1QXVGTjE4Hh0TJv75iz48R2eb93lG9zxpr8xhh1C7e0AAAAAWODcIFOqibQmHRL/fnDgtFy7JdNC7NynDGMtcucS4R5yD92+2UFPFquqfEbpu/gIW5eMv3LQIQDJlR5I53KRs"
    master_key = base64.b64decode(master_key)
    master_key = master_key[5:]
    master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
    return master_key

# Token codificado proporcionado
buff = base64.b64decode("djEwe5t74Rc5Ded4Ozm++rCKmYTCd7wxI1X6L1GywnslmeUs4240q72bcuotAMSp2p3S2ovrqQoFLRNJ9GzelmF+beLrVJfPnT7cdg+7e+ZRYBfn9uiTL/4VkL8Sp24TTgoVrDA+gg==")

# Obtener la clave maestra
master_key = get_master_key()

# Desencriptar el token
token_desencriptado = decrypt_val(buff, master_key)

print("Token desencriptado:", token_desencriptado)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oscar\OneDrive\Escritorio\read-leveldb\prube2.py", line 40, in <module>
    token_desencriptado = decrypt_val(buff, master_key)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Oscar\OneDrive\Escritorio\read-leveldb\prube2.py", line 18, in decrypt_val
    decrypted_pass += decryptor.finalize()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\base.py", line 227, in finalize
    data = self._ctx.finalize()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciphers.py", line 190, in finalize
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Authentication tag must be provided when decrypting.
```

I've tried different ways to decrypt the token, but I can't do it. Can someone lend me a hand?

This suggests that the encrypted token does not contain the authentication tag required to perform the decryption operation.

I've added this line to fix the problem but the problem persists`decrypted_pass = decryptor.update(payload) + decryptor.finalize()`

I have to say that I modified the token when uploading the script to the forum

Comment: I don't know what is going on in `get_master_key` but it looks kind of magical.

Comment: GCM usually uses an authentication tag, normally the last 16 bytes, i.e. `tag = buff[-16:]`. `payload` is to be shortened accordingly by 16 bytes, i.e. `payload = buff[15:-16]`. The tag is specified with the mode during decryption, see [`modes.GCM()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes.GCM). Consider the note on `AESGCM`.

Comment: You should provide more context, is it about decrypting Chrome cookies or passwords?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - Because of the DPAPI prefix, this could be a DPAPI-encrypted master key. E.g. Chrome on Windows encrypts the master key for cookie/password encryption this way.

Comment: The get_master_key() function seems to be a crucial component of a decryption process. This feature is designed to obtain the master key needed to decrypt encrypted data.

Here's an explanation of what the feature does:

Decodes a base64 string that represents the master key. The string is decoded using base64.b64decode.
The first 5 bytes of the decoded key are then ignored.
Use CryptUnprotectData from the win32crypt library to decrypt the key. It's based on GitHub code

Comment: @Topaco I'm trying to decrypt my Discord token

Comment: Try the suggested change. GCM requires a tag, which is usually appended to the ciphertext.

Comment: How do you know that the logic implemented in `decrypt_val()` is correct (3 bytes prefix, followed by a 12 bytes IV, followed by the cipheretxt)? Is this a guess or are you following some documentation?

Comment: @Topaco I used a github script as an example. Thank you, I have obtained the token and I want to make it clear that the script I have created is for research purposes only and at no time do I intend to bother anyone.